# H2O.ai implementation on EMR cluster

Tags: h2o

I am having trouble in deploying h2o.ai in a cluster in EMR. 
I am trying to installing with flatfile but it seems to be probing some issues in communicating with each other
Require help in this.

Comment: just want to double check, is this for h2o-3 open source product or for driverless-ai (note h2o.ai is the name of the company not a specific product). Thanks!

Comment: please also post the code you used and the error message you received so we can help you try to debug. Thanks!